# ruby - NoMethodError: undefined method `status'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to make a button which when clicked should change its status.(open <=> stop). However I have no idea, how to get the values of status. 
When I ran this code =>

```
@project.project_users.status = !@project.project_users.status # flop the status
```

It appeared !! `#<NoMethodError: undefined method 'status' for #<ProjectUser::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007feb80dcb540>>`.
Can somebody give me some methods to get `@project.project_users.status?` 
Thank you!

**controllers/project_users_controller.rb**

```
def flog
    @project.project_users.status = !@project.project_users.status # flop the status
    @project_user.save
    redirect_to project_project_user_path(project_user)
end
```

views/project_users/show.html.erb

```
<%= link_to (@project_user.status ? "open" : "stop"), flog_project_project_user_path(@project, @project_user) %>
```

config/routes.rb

```
resources :projects, only:[:index, :show, :new, :create, :mypage] do
resources :project_users, only:[:index, :show, :create] do
    member do
      get :flog
    end
end
```

models/project_user.rb

```
    enum status: { open: 1, stop: 2, hidden: 3, closed: 9 }
```

Comment: can you show us `Project` and `User` models ? If my guess is correct then `@project.project_users` is a collection not a single object, every object in this collection has `status` method but you can't access it as a method of the collection obviously

Comment: anyway changing a button's name when clicked is typically a thing done on the client side not server side so you need to do it in javascript :), without more explanation about your intentions of putting button's status in models I can't be sure though

Comment: As you said, @project.project_users is not a single object. I change my project_users into project_user. I can get the status value now. Thank you!

Comment: you're welcome, anyway I'd still consider doing it in javascript unless you really need to store that status field in database :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple issues here. First and foremost, you are trying to call an instance method on a *collection* of `project_users` - which is why you're seeing that error.

You would need to instead do something like:

```
@project.project_users.each do |project_user|
  project_user.status = !project_users.status
end
```

...Or maybe you can just access one of the collection like:

```
@project.project_user.status = !@project.project_user.status
```

...Or maybe what you actually intended here was:

```
@project_user.status = !@project_user.status
```

...But even *that* won't work, because you have defined `status` as an `enum` not a boolean. If you want to toggle the status between `open` and `stop`, then you'll need to write this in the code. (And also decide how to handle situations where the `status` is `hidden`/`closed`.)

By the way, if `status` *was* a boolean then you could use the built-in method: [`project_user.toggle!(:status)`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/toggle!) here.

You are also inconsistently using the word `flog`(??!) instead of `flop` for the route/controller action; you should probably fix that.

Comment: Thanks for your adivse! Yes,I found I used flog this wrong word.  And I changed my code into @project_user.status = !@project_user.status now.
How can I toggle the status between open and stop if status is not a boolean?

Comment: Naive attempt: `status == 'open' ? (status = 'closed') : (status = 'open')`. But as I said above, what happens if the status is `hidden` or `closed`?? This is something that you need to decide, and define properly in the code.

Comment: Also, you could make this a method on the `ProjectUser` model - so in the controller just call `@project_user.toggle_status`